# Exporting individual sheets to xml from OpenOffice Calc

Tags: xml, xslt, export, openoffice-calc

I am using import export xslt filters in OpenOffice 3.1.1 (Build 9420). There is a chunk of related data which I would like to have in a single ods file and then export selected sheets/cells using different xslt export filters. For e.g. -

Places, States, Events, Articles are presently separate ods files. But as they are related, it will be much better managed if they are in a single ods file. The exported xmls need to be separate and I already have xslt filters for each of the four.

So is it possible to have four sheets in a single ods file and then export them using relevant filters ?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the issue using below xslt code which looks for specific worksheet name and exports only that data.

```
<!-- This is required to exclude data that does not match required xpath -->
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//table:table[@table:name = 'Events']"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Process the document model -->
<xsl:template match="//table:table[@table:name = 'Events']">
    <!-- Some more xslt tags here -->
</xsl:template>
```

The attribute value "//table:table[@table:name = 'YourWorksheetName']" can be used to export data from specific worksheet.

Events is the worksheet name and this xslt file is set as one of the export filters in OpenOffice.